# Client Side React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to get React.js to work client side on my LAMP stack web application. I want to implement the following slider on my website: https://github.com/airbnb/rheostat. I have managed to get react.js to work using the following guide: https://gist.github.com/jineshshah36/4a0326abb191781184e9.

The following code works:

```
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
    var HelloComponent = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            return (
                <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
            )
        }
    })
    ReactDOM.render(<HelloComponent />, document.querySelector('#app'))
</script>
```

I tried to use the rheostat slider by changing the above to the following.

```
<div id="slider-root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/airbnb/rheostat/master/src/Slider.jsx"></script>
<link href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/airbnb/rheostat/master/css/slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/babel">
    import Rheostat from 'rheostat';
    ReactDOM.render(<Rheostat />, document.getElementById('slider-root'));
</script>
```

Am I importing the files wrong? Do I need to process the jsx file before it can be executed by the browser? If yes, how do I do that?

Comment: what error messages, if any, are you getting in your browser's console?

Comment: @DanO The console shows no errors.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to process the jsx file before it can be executed by the browser?

Yes, precisely. jsx is essentially a syntax extension primarily for working with React, and you will need to compile/transpile first. If you don't want to do that, you can simply leave jsx out altogether and just use:

```
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Rheostat), document.getElementById('slider-root'));
```

If you are interested in jsx, consider the following:

```
<div>
    <span>Text here</span>
</div>
```

This is not valid JavaScript, the browser will barf up all sorts of syntax errors restlessly. This code first has to be compiled, or *transpiled* into valid JavaScript. When using React, the above is to be compiled into:

```
React.createElement(
    "div",
    null,
    React.createElement(
        "span",
        null,
        "Text here"
    )
);
```

One of the most common tools for this is [Babel](https://babeljs.io/). [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) also has built-in support for typed jsx, dubbed tsx.

Comment: Thanks @John Weisz. What do I need to import in order to get `ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Rheostat), document.getElementById('slider-root'));` to work?

Comment: I also tried to load the jsx file using `type="text/babel"` but that throws a (syntax) error at me within the jsx file. I have imported babel (as shown in my example above). Do I need to import other files in order for this to work?

Comment: @Cellydy For the first part, you will obviously need `React`, `ReactDOM` and `Rheostat` imported, and AFAIK that's it. As for the second, I'm actually using TypeScript for jsx/tsx compilation, so I'm not sure how to pull this off with Babel. It's documentation will likely have a good guide.